# Typescript array of types with optional type

Tags: typescript

How would you type an array so it can accept array of  MyLetter[] and MyNumber or Array of MyLetter[], but nothing else.
if it's array of  MyLetter[] and MyNumber, it should be in the same order -> [MyLetter[] , MyNumber, MyLetter[] , MyNumber, ....]

```
type MyLetter = 'A' | 'B' | 'C'
type MyNumber = 1 | 3 | 5

valid example:
A: [['A', 'B'], 1, ['C', 'A'], 3]
B: [['B']]

invalid example:
A: [['A', 'B'], true, ['C', 'A'], 2]
B: ['B']
C: [1]
D: [1, ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'A'], 2]
```

Comment: In your description, when you say *"...array of MyLetter[]..."* do you literally mean `MyLetter[][]`? That would seem to be what you mean from your valid and invalid examples (`[['B']]` is valid, but `['B']` is invalid), but it's not really clear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I have edited the question. please let me know if still is not clear.

Comment: The invalid "C" option you've added ***really** wasn't clear from the original question. Allowing `MyNumber` only when there's a `MyLetter[]` elsewhere in the array is either very complicated or impossible in the general case. You can do a union type with various combinations of tuples, but...

Comment: A type like `[MyLetter[] , MyNumber, ...]`, where `...` is an unspecified number of repeating, sequential type arguments, is not possible. A tuple type must have a concrete length, and any solution to this is going to require that length at the point that you create it. Something like `type MyType = MyLetter[][] | [MyLetter[], MyNumber, MyLetter[], MyNumber]`. There are utility types and functions you could create to make this code easier to generate but they are quite complex and I'm not sure how useful it would be - let me know if you'd like to see it.